# Centerized authentication/Monitoring for network

Tags: network, domain-controller

I am looking for an open source solution to authenticate the machines before they use the network services (internet/local lan/smb etc).

Currently I am using MS Domain Environment . but DC does not handles mobiles or PDAs.

I have in my network , desktop PCs, laptops, Mobiles, PDA, in both wired and wireless.

I am looking for this outcome.

I want to monitor user activities with the network. either using Mobiles or PCs.

Solution I know.
1: MS Domain Controller. Can handle PCs and Laptops , who are running windows OS. (my clients might be running linux)
2: Mikrotik : can handle authentication over wireless for mobiles and PDAs.

I want single solution (preferably opensource) to authenticate wireless and wired client, running any OS  either mobiles or Desktop/Laptop.

Comment: It depends what protocols you need to use. You can use OpenDJ for LDAP, Samba Server 4 for Active Directory, Free Radius for EAP.